# Flutter GetX updating locale is resetting GoRouter navigation bug

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-go-router, flutter-localizations

I am using `GoRouter` for navigation and `GetX` for multiple things, including updating the app's `locale`.

It is updating the language perfectly fine, but the problem is that somehow my navigation stack is getting reset after the call.

I've made a [Screenvideo](https://gofile.io/d/f9amy5) for a better understanding but you can also test it yourself [here](https://onlychris-de18d.web.app/projects).

I update my locale by simply calling:

```
  Locale locale = Locale(languageCode);
  await Get.updateLocale(locale);
```

And my routing looks like this:

```
final rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

class AppRouter {
  static final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  static final router = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: IntroView.path,
    debugLogDiagnostics: true,
    navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
    routes: [
      ShellRoute(
        navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
        pageBuilder: (context, state, child) {
          return NoTransitionPage(
            child: ScaffoldView(
              child: child,
            ),
          );
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
            name: ProjectsView.name,
            path: '/projects',
            parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
            pageBuilder: (context, state) {
              return const FadePageTransition(
                page: ProjectsView(),
              );
            },
            routes: [
              GoRoute(
                parentNavigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
                path: ':projectTitle',
                pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                  return FadePageTransition(
                    page: ProjectDetailScaffold(
                      project: Projects.values.byName(
                        state.params['projectTitle']!,
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

I am already passing the `router` as instance and I am using `GetMaterialApp.router`:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final GoRouter router;
  const App({
    super.key,
    required this.router,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
       ...
      ],
      child: GetMaterialApp.router(
        routeInformationProvider: router.routeInformationProvider,
        routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
        routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
        translationsKeys: translationsKeys,
        locale: const Locale(LocaleConfiguration.baseLanguageCode),
        fallbackLocale: const Locale(LocaleConfiguration.baseLanguageCode),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Let me know if you need any more info!

Comment: Why are you using GoRouter when there is a navigator offered by GetX ?

Comment: @DeepShah I use GoRouter because it seems to be the best router for flutter web. At least from my experience. Especially useful for things like nested routing & parameterized routing

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I agree. GetX should definitely be used with caution. However I think it comes in quite handy for some helper functions. I like the way translation works and I never had any problems until now.

Comment: You might have to use named routing in GetX. 

For parameterizing, you can pass query params using GetX.

Answer (score 0):

For now I found a workaround that is not very clean but it works for me:

Right after I call `await Get.updateLocale(locale);` I am calling this:

```
  if (mounted) {
    while (context.canPop()) {
      context.pop();
    }
    context.pushReplacement('/projects/localizeIt');
  }
```

The problem is that `GoRouter` loses the state because `updateLocale` forces the app to rebuild. As workaround, I am popping all views and going to the location where I am calling `updateLocale` from.

Like I said, this is no ideal and more of a workaround. If anyone know a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your current workaround involves essentially restarting the navigation stack and redirecting to a specific page after changing the locale, and while this might work, it does seem a bit rough and could potentially lead to user experience issues.

In Flutter, the locale change does indeed cause a rebuild of the widget tree. However, it seems unusual that the navigation stack is getting cleared in this process. Generally, the navigation stack should be maintained across rebuilds unless explicitly cleared or modified.

The issue could potentially be related to how [`GetX`](https://chornthorn.github.io/getx-docs/) and [`GoRouter`](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) interact with each other.

- `GetX` is a state management solution, and it seems to be causing a full rebuild of the widget tree when the locale changes.
- `GoRouter` on the other hand, manages navigation and should maintain its state across widget tree rebuilds.

So you can try and ensure the `GoRouter` instance is not being recreated on each rebuild. The router should be created once and maintained for the duration of the app's lifetime.

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final router = AppRouter.router;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerDelegate: router.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: router.routeInformationParser,
    );
  }
}
```

And consider separating your localization and routing concerns.
Instead of calling `Get.updateLocale` directly, you could create a separate service that wraps this call and also preserves your navigation state. This service could listen for locale changes and update the locale without causing a full rebuild of the widget tree.

```dart
class LocaleService extends GetxController {
  void updateLocale(String languageCode) async {
    Locale locale = Locale(languageCode);
    Get.updateLocale(locale);
    update();
  }
}

class LocaleSwitcher extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<LocaleService>(
      init: LocaleService(),
      builder: (controller) {
        return DropdownButton<String>(
          value: Get.locale?.languageCode,
          items: <String>['en', 'fr', 'de'].map((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(value),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (newValue) {
            controller.updateLocale(newValue!);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

`LocaleService` is a service that wraps the `Get.updateLocale` call.
`LocaleSwitcher` is a widget that uses `GetBuilder` to listen for changes in `LocaleService`, and rebuilds itself when the locale is updated.
This way, only the `LocaleSwitcher` widget is rebuilt when the locale changes, not the entire widget tree.

---

Or: consider using `GetMaterialApp` which integrates `GetX` with the Flutter `MaterialApp` widget (as [illustrated here](https://pub.dev/packages/get#counter-app-with-getx)). This might help with preserving the navigation state when changing locale.
See also "[What is the difference between GetMaterialApp of GetX and MaterialApp of Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74016602/6309)".
That would also mean you are relying on `GetX` for routing instead of `GoRouter`. If you want to stick with `GoRouter` for routing, the first two points are enough.
However, if you are okay with transitioning to `GetX` for routing, using `GetMaterialAp`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I already implemented the first solution. I updated my question. And I just tried the 2nd approach but this is giving me the same result. The router is still reset.

Comment: @Chris OK. The underlying problem might lie within the interaction between `GetX` and `GoRouter` when the widget tree is rebuilt.